# How to change the text style of MFC CEdit control?

Tags: visual-c++, fonts, mfc, editcontrol

I am making dialog based programs with MFC.
How do I change the text of the edit control to bold or change the size?
Where and what kind of code should I write?
Please tell me specifically.

Answer (score 4):

In your `OnInitDialog`, create a `CFont` object (declared in your dialog)

```c++
    m_pFont=new CFont;

    int lfHeight;
    lfHeight = (int) -(dSize* 90 / 72.);

    int nWeight=FW_NORMAL;
    if ( isBold )
        nWeight=FW_BOLD;
    pFont->CreateFont( lfHeight , 0, 0, 0, nWeight, (BYTE)isItalic, (BYTE)isUnderline, 0, (BYTE)nCharSet, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, _T("Arial") );
```

And then call `SetFont(m_pFont)` for your edit control - delete it in your destructor.